# TFS 2005: Error messages when creating a development instance

Tags: tfs, tfs-2005

I'm attempting to create a Dev instance of TFS 2005 (non SP1) with a view to test SP1.  We're using dual server mode.

So far, I've installed TFS on my App machine, restored the db from prod on my database machine, and updated references in my db.  Also ran the usual tfsadminutil commands.

When I open VS2005 and attempt to connect to TFS, I get this error:

```
Team Foundation Server scdctstmp01 does not exist or is not accessible at this time. Technical information (for administrator):   HTTP code 503: TF30059: Fatal error while initializing web service
```

The event log on my app machine gives 2 errors:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   TFS Version Control
Event Category: None
Event ID:   3023
Date:       1/12/2011
Time:       2:23:53 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   SCDCTSTMP01
Description:
TF53010: An unexpected condition has occurred in a Team Foundation component. The information contained here should be made available to your site administrative staff.
Technical Information (for the administrative staff):
Date (UTC): 1/12/2011 6:23:53 AM
Machine: SCDCTSTMP01
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/Root/VersionControl-6-129671942250700000
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 4440
  Thread Id: 4660
  Account name: JUSTICE\svctfsservicetest

Detailed Message: TF14073: The stored download key is not valid.  The key will be regenerated.
Web Request Details
    Url: http://scdctstmp01:8080/VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 8.0.50727.147)
    Headers: Content-Length=319&Content-Type=application%2fsoap%2bxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8&Accept-Encoding=gzip%2cgzip%2cgzip&Accept-Language=en-AU&Authorization=NTLM+TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHgAAAAYABgAkAAAAA4ADgBIAAAAEAAQAFYAAAASABIAZgAAABAAEACoAAAANYKI4gUBKAoAAAAPSgBVAFMAVABJAEMARQBSAGEAdABpAGwAYQBsAEEAVwBLAFMANQAzADcAMgA2ADEAPY1tpAEvSp0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAyQBeCmtO9f7LX%2fiQDfGQkQsvS8PePBVfQSawM960yZWsaavouGJD6A%3d%3d&Expect=100-continue&Host=scdctstmp01%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe%2c+8.0.50727.147)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-VersionControl-Instance=182973de-f5c6-4c0f-9895-91f36f476551
    Path: /VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx
    Local Request: False
    Host Address: 10.96.144.249
    User: JUSTICE\RatilalA [authentication type: NTLM]

Exception Message: Keyset does not exist
 (type CryptographicException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle._FreeCSP(IntPtr pProvCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle.ReleaseHandle()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalDispose()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.Proxy.RequestSignatures.GetKeyInformation(Byte[] privateKey, Int32& keyLength, Byte[]& publicKey)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.RepositoryProperties.set_PrivateKey(Byte[] value)



For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

and

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   TFS Version Control
Event Category: None
Event ID:   3000
Date:       1/12/2011
Time:       2:23:59 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   SCDCTSTMP01
Description:
TF53010: An unexpected condition has occurred in a Team Foundation component. The information contained here should be made available to your site administrative staff.
Technical Information (for the administrative staff):
Date (UTC): 1/12/2011 6:23:59 AM
Machine: SCDCTSTMP01
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/Root/VersionControl-6-129671942250700000
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 4440
  Thread Id: 4660
  Account name: JUSTICE\svctfsservicetest

Detailed Message: TF14000: A critical error occured while generating new download key. Shutting down the current AppDomain
Web Request Details
    Url: http://scdctstmp01:8080/VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 8.0.50727.147)
    Headers: Content-Length=319&Content-Type=application%2fsoap%2bxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8&Accept-Encoding=gzip%2cgzip%2cgzip&Accept-Language=en-AU&Authorization=NTLM+TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHgAAAAYABgAkAAAAA4ADgBIAAAAEAAQAFYAAAASABIAZgAAABAAEACoAAAANYKI4gUBKAoAAAAPSgBVAFMAVABJAEMARQBSAGEAdABpAGwAYQBsAEEAVwBLAFMANQAzADcAMgA2ADEAPY1tpAEvSp0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAyQBeCmtO9f7LX%2fiQDfGQkQsvS8PePBVfQSawM960yZWsaavouGJD6A%3d%3d&Expect=100-continue&Host=scdctstmp01%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe%2c+8.0.50727.147)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-VersionControl-Instance=182973de-f5c6-4c0f-9895-91f36f476551
    Path: /VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx
    Local Request: False
    Host Address: 10.96.144.249
    User: JUSTICE\RatilalA [authentication type: NTLM]

Exception Message: Keyset does not exist
 (type CryptographicException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle._FreeCSP(IntPtr pProvCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle.ReleaseHandle()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalDispose()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.Proxy.RequestSignatures.GenerateNewPrivateKey(Int32 keyLength)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.AdministrationManager.GenerateRepositoryKey(Int32 keyLength)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.Global.Initialize()



For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Anyone knows what the issue is?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the database I was copying was SP1, while my test server was not.

To find TFS version: Navigate to 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Team Foundation Server\Web Services\Services\bin
Right click on Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.dll, Properties, Version
File version 8.0.50727.762 = SP1.
File version 8.0.50727.147 = RTM.